# Set field value for single database row

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, model

I'm trying to update a row on my `profiles` table to reset a users profile picture to the default of `user.png`. I have the following action in my controller:

```
public function deleteProfilePicture() {
    $this->layout = 'ajax';

    // First find the profile ID from the user ID
    $profileId = $this->Profile->find('first', array(
        'condition' => array('User.id' => $this->Auth->user('id')),
        'fields' => array('Profile.id'),
        'recursive' => -1
    ));

    $this->Profile->id = $profileId['Profile']['id'];
    $this->Profile->saveField('picture', 'user.png', false);
}
```

However, when I request the URL (`/profile/deleteProfilePicture`) I get no errors but the database row isn't updated. I have made sure the current profile ID is used by using `debug($profileId)`.

What could be going wrong here?

Edit: The return value of `saveField()`:

```
array(
    'Profile' => array(
        'id' => '36',
        'modified' => '2013-04-05 14:16:57'
    )
)
```

Comment: What's the return value of saveField() call? It's likely you have a model or behavior beforeSave() callback which returns false thereby preventing the update.

Comment: check the generated sql and try executing it directly on the DB.. maybe there's something wrong there

Comment: I've edited the return value of `saveField()` into the original question. @pleasedontbelong how would I find the SQL it's executing?

Comment: maybe off topic, but it should read 'conditions' not 'condition' in your find()

Comment: Strange behaviour, the `modified` field of the row gets updated, but not `picture`. :/

Comment: Seems cake is not "seeing" your picture field. Make sure your field name casing is exactly the same. Clear model cache and check.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647065/how-can-i-see-cakephps-sql-dump-in-the-controller
 or you could temporaly add the sqldump element on the ajax layout

Comment: Update, looks like the `beforeSave()` method is stopping it from saving. Is there a way to bypass beforeSave()?

Comment: Use the [third param](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-Model.html#_saveField) of saveField() and set 'callbacks' option to false.

Answer (score 1):

Try

`$this->Profile->id = $profileId['Profile']['id'];
$this->Profile->set(array(
    'picture' => 'user.png'
));
$this->Post->save();`

Answer (score 1):

I see no error in your code. Try seeing what query is getting executed using this

```
$log = $this->Model->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false);
  debug($log);
```

based on the result make changes to your query if you find something wrong.

Or try using this

```
$data['Profile']['id']=$profileId['Profile']['id'];
$data['Profile'['picture']='user.png';
$this->Profile->save($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set debug to 2 you could see what SQL is being executed, see if your update is actually firing.

Comment: The query being executed only updates the `modified` field for some reason, it's not touching `picture` at all, despite me explicitly telling it to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->Profile->read(null, $profileId['Profile']['id']);
$this->Profile->saveField('picture', 'user.png', false);
```

Why are you setting the validation to false? Do you get an error if you omit that?