# cakephp 3.0 SQL QUEry

Tags: sql, cakephp-3.0

How to view sql query at the bottom of pages?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want to show your queries on the bottom of the page when it's completed rendering, you might want to try one of these options:

[How can I see CakePHP's SQL dump in the controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647065/how-can-i-see-cakephps-sql-dump-in-the-controller)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: What about in Cake 3.3?